# Customer UINavigation Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'd like to create a subclass of the UINavigationController, so that I can set a specific style throughout my app - for example, a white font and a blue background.

I'm using swift, so I wrote this code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class NavigationController : UINavigationController {
  override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.navigationBar.translucent = false

  }
}
```

I then changed the class of my navigation controller in the storyboard to this class - however this didn't work. It just did nothing, however when I remove the translucent = false line, I get a vaguely blue looking navigationBar.

What am I doing wrong? All the references on here I can find don't do it in this way or don't use swift.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess what you want to do is this:

`self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()`